# How do I create a new Joda DateTime truncated to the last hour?

Tags: java, datetime, truncate, jodatime, floor

I am pulling timestamps from a file that I want to create a new DateTime for, but I want to create the DateTime at the floor of the hour (or any Joda Period will do).
How Can I do this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Wohoo, found it. Simple like everything in Joda once I traced down the calls.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime().hourOfDay().roundFloorCopy();
```